# How to create mutually exclusive table columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, mutual-exclusion

I have a table Transactions where I am saving two records for one transaction, one for debiting and other crediting.

So I have two columns in table `creditAmount(Money)` and `debitAmount(Money)`.

I want a table level constraint that either of the column is not null in each row.
i.e. If row #3 `creditAmount` is null then `debitAmount` must hold some value and Vice Versa.

How to ensure the same when inserting a record in a row?

Comment: Why not one column and a flag indicating `C` or `D`?

Comment: Just curious, but why isn't the sign of a single value adequate to indicate credit or debit?

Comment: Thats the requirement, I cant change it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can add a [CHECK constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179491%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE Transactions ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Transactions_DebitOrCreditExists
CHECK ((creditAmount IS NULL AND debitAmount IS NOT NULL) 
   OR (creditAmount IS NOT NULL AND debitAmount IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling via Front-end (your application), then the issue of both Credit and Debit being null won't arise. At least one entry is inserted, either in Debit or Credit.

I guess you want to put a constraint when someone is handling via back-end and directly inserting values in a table. In that case, Chris suggested a solution.

But even if you are inserting from back-end, I am not following why I would record a transaction when neither it is Debit nor Credit.

Comment: Actually its a service and as a service dev I cant totally rely on data sent to me. So, its just for precaution.

Comment: Its good to validate your data at all levels. C.f. the case where someone is manually entering data into the db and bypassing any front-end or indeed business layer validation logic.